# Include externally hosted images with Dragonfly + WickedPDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf, dragonfly-gem

I am using `wicked_pdf` to generate PDFs and `dragonfly` + S3 for image handling.  Is it possible to render externally hosted images in a PDF using `wicked_pdf`?  `wicked_pdf` requires absolute paths, but I've had no luck in getting the two to work together nicely.

Comment: This can be done, using external URL(image) and rendering in `wicked_pdf` is possible. Have you tried `src` attribute? I have done in my previous project, I don't have the code right now.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? Did you try using absolute paths to your S3 assets, and got broken images in the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue on `dragonfly + S3` but using an external `URL` in **wicked pdf** is fairly simple

> `<%= image_tag  'url' %>`

This was trail and error method which I had tried, and it got clicked ;)